NA values when running summary statistics for NSCH data in R using mitools and survey packages
I am working with NSCH data for the first time in R. I found the following resource, which has been enormously helpful (thank you!).
https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/master/nsch.Rmd
I followed the above code from the github repository completely for importing, setting up, and reshaping the data and creating the survey design. It ran completely fine. I only began to make modifications once I started to try to calculate summary statistics for other variables. Although the variables in the examples generate summary statistics (e.g., age, poverty level), I am producing NAs for the other variables I attempt to generate summary statistics for.
I attempted to replicate the example code below to get summary statistics on one of the numeric variables, ace5.
#Calculate the mean (average) of a linear variable, overall and by groups:
#example code below
MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ sc_age_years ) ) )

#My code
MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ ace5 ) ) )


Age calculates fine:
results
<dbl>
se
<dbl>
sc_age_years    8.839863    0.04435024

However, I get NA values for ace5.
results
<dbl>
se
<dbl>
ace5    NA  NA      

I also tried converting ace5 to a factor variable and then calculating survey totals:
nsch_design <-
    update(
        nsch_design ,
ace5f = factor(
      ifelse(ace5 == 1, "Yes", ifelse(ace5 == 2, "No", NA)),
      levels = c("Yes", "No")
        )
)

MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svytotal( ~ ace5f ) ) )

results
<dbl>
se
<dbl>
ace5fYes    NA  NaN     
ace5fNo NA  NaN 

That syntax also produces NAs. I have tried the syntax with some of the other numeric variables in the dataset (e.g., cavities), and am still producing NAs.
Does anyone have any ideas why I would be getting NA values when trying to compute summary statistics for these variables?
(I am not sure how to generate a minimally reproducible example with a large, complex, multiply imputed dataset, but open to suggestions).

Please post sample of data with dput and even the structure of data with str to confirm data types.

does the na.rm option shown on the ?svymean help page give you the behavior you're looking for?  thanks!!
# fails
MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ ace5 ) ) )

# works but gives wrong answer since it's averaging ones and twos
MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ ace5 , na.rm = TRUE ) ) )

# works
MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ factor( ace5 ) , na.rm = TRUE ) ) )

# works
MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ as.numeric( ace5 == 1 ) , na.rm = TRUE ) ) )

# works
MIcombine( with( subset( nsch_design , !is.na( ace5 ) ) , svymean( ~ as.numeric( ace5 == 1 ) ) ) )

# works but wrong!  incorrectly includes missings in the denominator
MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ as.numeric( ace5 %in% 1 ) ) ) )


You are my hero. This worked: MIcombine( with( nsch_design , svymean( ~ factor( ace5 ) , na.rm = TRUE ) ) ) I had tried na.rm=T but formatted it wrong. Thank you, thank you!
